# How to get MySQL to return the correct year number for "week 53 of 2012" using "mode 7"

Tags: mysql, week-number

How would I get MySQL to tell me that '**2013**-01-01' is week number 53 of **2012**?

I'm using [mode 7](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) for the definition of a week.

I can get the week number easily enough by using `WEEK('2013-01-01', 7)`

The problem is that, of course, `YEAR('2013-01-01')` returns `2013`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`YEARWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function lets you pass the mode to it as well. The only downside is that it returns the year and week-in-year combined together:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK('2013-01-01', 7);

>> 201253
```

You can get around that with [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), though, if you really need just the year separately:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(YEARWEEK('2013-01-01', 7), 1, 4);

>> 2012
```

Comment: Great!  Thanks.  Don't know how I missed that one.